# After guard implementation, the unauthorized url return to main screen not showing data

Tags: angular6, laravel-5.6

When I run the angular app, it redirects to localhost:4200/events page where I have data to be displayed. Now I have implemented guard service as beforelogin & afterlogin to let allow user to access the certain page before and after login.

Example: if the user is not logged-in and if the user hits url "localhost:4200/special" directly I want it redirect to localhost:4200/events page but instead it redirect to localhost:4200 page. I have tried to display data to this localhost:4200 page as well but data is not being displayed.

Instead of

```
path:'', redirectTo: 'events',
```

I have also tried:

```
path:'', component: EventComponent
```

### app-routing.module.ts

```
import { BeforeLoginGuard } from './guards/before-login.guard';
import { AfterLoginGuard } from './guards/after-login.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: 'events',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        canActivate: [BeforeLoginGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent,
        canActivate: [BeforeLoginGuard]

    }
    {
        path: 'events',
        component: EventsComponent
    }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

### after-login.guard

```
export class AfterLoginGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        return this._tokenService.loggedIn();
    }

    constructor(private _tokenService: TokenService) { }
}
```

### events.component

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

    events = [];

    constructor(private _eventService: EventService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._eventService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
                res => this.events = res,
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }

}
```